# Как спарсить результат google

Tags: python, python-2.x

Как сделать так, чтобы сценарий парсил что выведет google и добавлял в список адреса сайтов, которые вывел google?

Comment: https://github.com/abenassi/Google-Search-API

Comment: Что-то не могу понять как реализовать: from google import google
num_page = 1
search_results = google.search("test", num_page).link() 
print search_results <-- выдает ошибку

Comment: Пойдите почитайте пару книг по тестированию продукта... А то так как сейчас, что-либо исправить не предоставляеться возможности...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
from google import google
search_results = google.search("test")
for result in search_results:
    print result.link
```

В вашем коде были 2 ошибки:

1. `search_results` это список, по нему надо итерировать, чтобы получить ссылки
2. `link` это свойство, не метод